# Как использовать методы оригинального типа после создания кастомного? Golang

Tags: golang

Представим что я создаю кастомный тип времени:

```
type CustomTime time.Time
```

В него помещается какое-то значение. Допустим теперь я хочу это время привести к строке. Но если я попытаюсь сделать:

```
var myTime CustomTime
myTime.Format("2006-01-02 15:04:05")
```

То получу ошибку, что тип `CustomTime` не имеет метода `Format`. Как это использовать? Какой вообще смысл от кастомных типов если они не имеют доступ к методам оригинальных типов?

Comment: [Встраивайте](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36094060/reusing-the-methods-of-the-base-type-in-the-derived-custom-type-in-golang) ваш базовый тип внутрь новой структуры.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

к сожалению, так нельзя сделать, так как ваш новый тип не содержит данного метода. Но есть разные решения,

композиция - мы сами определим какие методы нам нужны

```
type CustomTime time.Time

func (t CustomTime) Format(layout string) string {
    return time.Time(t).Format(layout)
}

func NewCustomTime(t time.Time) CustomTime {
    return CustomTime(t)
}
```

либо использовать встраивание ("наследование")

```
type CustomTime struct {
    time.Time
}

var t CustomTime
t.Format("")
```

поиграете с полным [примером](https://play.golang.org/p/VfSRO1bKpgr)

```
package main

import "fmt"

type A struct {
    s string
}

func (a A) MethodOnA() string {
    return a.s + " from A"
}

type B struct {
    s string
    A
}

type C struct {
    s string
    a A
}

func main() {
    a := A{s: "whatever A"}
    b := B{s: "whatever B", A: a}
    c := C{s: "whatever C", a: a}
    fmt.Println("B", b.MethodOnA())   // but also b.A.MethodOnA()
    fmt.Println("C", c.a.MethodOnA()) // c.MethodOnA() will not compile
}
```